# select arrow style change when <select multiple="multiple" >

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have found plenty of tutorials on how to change the arrow colors of a  however they don't work where multiple is set to multiple="multiple" and I have TWO arrows rather than one.

The website is textatradesman.com, The HTML is as follow:

```
<select id="select" multiple="multiple">  
                <option class="clicktoselect" value="">Click or Tap to Select</option>
                    <option value="http://www.Textabuilder.co.uk/">TextA Builder.co.uk</option>  
                    <option value="http://www.Textaplumber.co.uk/">TextA Plumber.co.uk</option> 
                    <option value="http://www.Textalocksmith.co.uk/">TextA Locksmith.co.uk</option>
                    <option value="http://www.Textahandyman.co.uk/">TextA Handyman.co.uk</option>
                    <option value="http://www.Textapainter.co.uk/">TextA Painter.co.uk</option>
                    <option value="http://www.Textacarpenter.co.uk/">TextA Carpenter.co.uk</option> 
                    <option value="http://www.Textaplasterer.co.uk/">TextA Plasterer.co.uk</option>            
                    <option value="http://www.Textatiler.co.uk/">TextA Tiler.co.uk</option>  
                    <option value="http://www.Textabricklayer.co.uk/">TextA Bricklayer.co.uk</option>   
                    <option value="http://www.Textaboilerrepair.co.uk/">TextA Boilerrepair.co.uk</option>   
                    <option value=".">A - Z List of trades below....</option>   
                    <option value="http://www.TextaApplianceRepair.co.uk/">TextA ApplianceRepair.co.uk</option>                     
                    <option value="http://www.textanacrepair.co.uk/">TextA ACRepair.co.uk</option>                      
                    <option value="http://www.textanalarmfitter.co.uk/">TextA AlarmFitter.co.uk</option>    
                    <option value="http://www.Textaarchitect.co.uk/">TextA Architect.co.uk</option> 
                    <option value="http://www.textaasphalter.co.uk/">TextA Asphalter.co.uk</option>                                     


                    <option value="http://www.Textafrenchpolisher.co.uk/">TextA FrenchPolisher.co.uk</option>                       
                    <option value="http://www.Textagaragedoorfitter.co.uk/">TextA GarageDoorFitter.co.uk</option>                       
                    <option value="http://www.Textagardener.co.uk/">TextA Gardener.co.uk</option>                                               

                    <option value="http://www.Textawindowfitter.co.uk/">TextA WindowFitter.co.uk</option>
         </select>
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear, what I want to do is to change the colour of the down/ up arrows, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Simple `<select>` has one arrow. Multiple `<select>` has two arrows. What's the problem? If you don't like arrows, you can add a combo plugin like `chosen` or `select2` from jquery.

You can explain better the problem and what you like to achieve.

Comment: Marcos, I want the down arrow and the up arrow to be red, that's all, thanks for replying. The other solutions I tried that ''hidden'' the arrow and replaced it with another one didn't work, I ended up with one arrow only.. another solution I tried wouldn't work once I increased the height..

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Unfortunately, arrows can't be stylized in all browsers and all operating systems. You can add colors specifically for Chrome and IE, but not in the other browsers. For example, see this with chrome and then with other browser: http://jsfiddle.net/avm99963/rA5Ra/4/ it only runs in chrome. For styling scrollbars and its arrows you can only make it with javascript (handwritting or inserting an existing plugin).